# "mysqldump > mysql" throws error. Why?

Tags: shell, redirect

I am somewhat newbie for linux, still learning.

Today I needed to duplicate a database into production environment.. To do this, I used the command

```
(uiserver):u70486952:~ > mysqldump -h host -u user --password=mypassword dbname > mysql -h host2 -u user2 --password=mypassword dbname2
```

This command, while looking ok to me did not work and it threw an error.

```
mysqldump: Got error: 1044: Access denied for user 'user'@'%' to database 'dbname' when selecting the database
```

Doing this alone (without the > after the command) worked.
I solved this using a pipe character instead of > (more than).

Can someone explain why it showed an errror? I am very curious.

Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Redirection can be performed anywhere in a command, and only the very next word is used as the filename; anything else on the command line is passed as arguments to the command. That is,

```
mysqldump -h host -u user --password=mypassword dbname > mysql -h host2 -u user2 --password=mypassword dbname2
```

is equivalent to

```
mysqldump -h host -u user --password=mypassword dbname -h host2 -u user2 --password=mypassword dbname2 > mysql
```

Comment: Thank you. Make sense. Learned something today! :)